# Url called from flash asks from a logged user to login again

Tags: nodes, blocks

I have a flash animation in a block which has a link to a different page in my site. The problem is that even if the user is logged in my website, the link when it opens, asks for credentials again. Any ideas how to overcome this problem?

I use the following code for the block:

```
<p>
  <object align="middle" height="380" width="100%">
    <param name="scale" value="exactfit" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="movie" value="/sites/default/files/flashes/main_tools.swf" />
    <embed height="380" pluginspage="macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"; quality="high" scale="exactfit" src="/sites/default/files/flashes/main_tools.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" wmode="transparent"></embed>
  </object>
</p>
```

Comment: Check the user permissions for those pages

Comment: Do you have any custom code around this block/flash animation? Or did you just paste the embed code into the block body, surrounded by an `<a>` tag?

Comment: Are you sure it is the same URL? I mean, if user is logged in on example.com he may be logged off on www.example.com - for example.

Comment: @Molot I followed your advice and edited the .htaccess to redirect all users to access the site with the www prefix which actually did the trick since flash had a url that was using the www as a prefix. Thanks a lot!